# What should if I want to make API call using flow between View and Viewmodel in Kotlin-Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

So there are Flow, SharedFlow, StateFlow, MutableSharedFlow, MutableStateFlow, `FlowCollector flow {..}`

Requirement:

I want to make an API call from View and if API fails, on click of retry button user can make an API call again. I do not want to use Live data or mutable live data between view and ViewModel, I want to use Flow. Which flow I should use please suggest that.

I'm using clean and core MVVM architecture in my Android project to make an API call.
Activity/Fragment - Viewmodel - Repo - DataSource - Retrofit

So for all the layer I'm using flow like this:

```
override fun getUserReviewData(): Flow<Resource<ReviewResponse>> = flow {
    userRemoteDataSource.getUserReviewResponse().collect {
        emit(it)
    }
}
```

Interface

```
fun getUserReviewData(): Flow<Resource<ReviewResponse>
```

Now what should I use between Viewmodel and view?

Viewmodel:

```
var userReviewData = emptyFlow<Resource<ReviewResponse>>()

fun fetchUserReviewData() {
    userReviewData = flow {
        emit(Resource.loading(true))

        repository.getUserReviewData().collect {
            emit(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow. Also, your `getUserReviewData` can be rewritten to `override fun getUserReviewData() = userRemoteDataSource.getUserReviewResponse()`. There's no point to collect and then emit again